# Nested SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

I have problems with the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT job
FROM (SELECT job, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Employee
GROUP BY job)
WHERE cnt=1
```

As Result it should only shows all jobs where cnt (count of jobs) equals 1.
When I test the select query above on Fiddle, I get following error :

```
   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d812a/7

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d812a/15

Comment: Is the expected result Baker and Gardener ?

Comment: You could also use HAVING, which would make the outer query redundant

Comment: @Loufylouf - Yes Baker, Gardener would be the correct result.

Comment: Strawberry, could u give me an example with HAVING-Clausel?

Comment: I dont think there is need of subquery to increase complexity, try my answer given below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to increase complexity by using sub-query when it is not require

```
SELECT job, count(job)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY job
having count(job)=1;
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks really simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide alias name to the nested query

```
SELECT A.job
FROM (SELECT job, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Employee
GROUP BY job)A
WHERE A.cnt=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the alias name.
Please change the query like this

```
SELECT job
FROM (SELECT job, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Employee
GROUP BY job) As MyTable
WHERE cnt=1
```

You should have to give the alias name for the inner query when you are using the select and where clauses outside.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks for mentioned it - but I guess I will use HAVING-Clausel for it.

Comment: That one is fine and it is differnet than what you asked. I corrected your Query. and if it is worked and if it is the direct answer your question then upvote and accept. Check the Question that have asked , Not the alternative solution right?

Comment: You are right, I would upvote, when I have enough reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `HAVING` clause which is done for that kind of thing. Your request will be simply :

```
SELECT job FROM Employee GROUP BY job
HAVING COUNT(id)=1
```

The documentation states that

> The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in
>   the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However,
>   MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to
>   refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as
>   well.

The important thing to note is that contrary to the `WHERE` clause, you can use aggregate funcitons (like count, max, min ...) in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `HAVING` syntax :

```
SELECT job, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Employee
GROUP BY job
HAVING cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it returns an error. The aggregate function should be used directly in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: It depends of your SQL mode. If you have disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, it should work.